# AWS Athena (Presto with JsonSerde) fails quietly on some Column Names, which ones are acceptable?

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

I tried creating this simple table in Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ctc.rets (
  `SystemID` string,
  `blah` string
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'mapping.SystemID' = 'L_ListingID',
  'mapping.blah' = 'Ext_Char10_11' 
) 
LOCATION 's3://xyz.bucket/mydata/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

The field named `blah` maps fine, but the field named `SystemID` comes up blank on every row.

And then it gets really interesting:

- I change the `SystemID` field name to `WTF`, or `foobar`, or `strawberry`, and **it works fine** (the data shows up).
- I change the `SystemID` field name to `_SystemID`, `f_SystemID`, `ystemID`, `System_I_D`, and **none of them work**

There is never an error message.

What are the actual rules that need to be followed for the field names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, mapping with SerDe is done to map reserved field name to the non-reserved one. The pattern is below:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'mapping.NON_RESERVED_KEYWORD' = 'RESERVED_KEYWORD'
)
```

Real example from [github](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#mapping-hive-keywords):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    myfield string, ts string
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.ts" = "timestamp" )
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Mapping is done as `timestamp` is reserved keyword.

In you, case System_ID should be flipped. Also, I've checked in the [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords) and `System_ID` is not reserved keyword.

***OP UPDATE***:
After some additional experimentation, I also determined you cannot use mixed-case in the NON_RESERVED_KEYWORD. All uppercase or all lowercase is fine.